# iPhone SDK - how to create menu with buttons

Tags: iphone, sdk

How can I create something like this http://goo.gl/ks2q1 (which is under "Actions")?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: That would be a UITableView set to grouped cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be easy process just use second section of table view and create a label insert in cell and make it center.Use this line of code in your table method.

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 if(indexPath.section==1)
    {
        putts_Label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 8, 24, 24)];
        putts_Label.text=@"0";

        putts_Label.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        putts_Label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:putts_Label];
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know name of it

Comment: If it is helpful for you inform us comment it here.

Comment: @user1307957 if this answer or any other has helped you, mark it as correct by clicking the "check mark" next to the answer. I've noticed that you haven't marked a correct answer to any of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a normal `UITableView`, take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [UITableView Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know name of it

Comment: You are welcome, the TableView is quite simple so posting the code might not make sense for you until you understand the functioning, then if you have any problem make a more detailed question and someone will help you to solve the problem. Oh, and if you think that an answer is correct, mark it as accepted, if that is super-useful upvote it!